# how make float to integer in awk

Tags: awk

I have a variable in my awk code . after some arithmetic operation on this variable and printing (`print $1,$2,variable`) the result is made like below:

**my result**

```
Bama     2   5    
Bama     2   5.001
Bama     2   5.002
Bama     2   5.003
Bama     2   5.004
Bama     2   6  
Bama     2   6.003
Bama     2   6.004
Bama     2   4.005
```

But I want only integer section of my variable print

**desired result**

```
Bama     2   5    
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   6  
Bama     2   6
Bama     2   6
Bama     2   4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: **`1)`** [How to convert floating point number to integer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89712/), **`2)`** [How to round floating point numbers in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167058/)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Truncate it using the `int` function:

```
print $1, $2, int( variable );
```

Comment: or use printf "%s %s %d\n", $1, $2, variable

Comment: POSIX 7: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html

Answer (score 1):

To keep exactly same spacing and everything:

```
awk -F ' ' '{print $1"     "$2"   "int($3)}' data.lst
```

this trims, does not round, so `4.9` will become `4`.

A dirty way is to use the point as field separator:

```
awk -F '.' '{print $1}' data.lst
```

Input:

```
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5.001
Bama     2   5.002
Bama     2   5.003
Bama     2   5.004
Bama     2   6
Bama     2   6.003
Bama     2   6.004
Bama     2   4.905
```

Output in either case:

```
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   5
Bama     2   6
Bama     2   6
Bama     2   6
Bama     2   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` instead of `print` and specify the integer format:

```bash
$ echo Bama 2 5.001 | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }'
Bama 2 5.001
$ echo Bama 2 5.001 | awk '{ printf "%s %d %d\n",$1,$2,$3 }'
Bama 2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on whether you want to have it **rounded** instead of just giving you the **floor** for `non-negatives`, or **ceiling** for `negatives` :

> ```
> mawk '{ print _=$-__, int(_), sprintf("%d", _)
>                               sprintf("%.f",_) }'
> ```

```
4.00000000 4 4 4           -5.00000000 -5 -5 -5
4.11111111 4 4 4           -4.88888889 -4 -4 -5
4.22222222 4 4 4           -4.77777778 -4 -4 -5
4.33333333 4 4 4           -4.66666667 -4 -4 -5
4.44444444 4 4 4           -4.55555556 -4 -4 -5

4.50000000 4 4 4           -4.50000000 -4 -4 -4

4.55555556 4 4 5           -4.44444444 -4 -4 -4
4.66666667 4 4 5           -4.33333333 -4 -4 -4
4.77777778 4 4 5           -4.22222222 -4 -4 -4
4.88888889 4 4 5           -4.11111111 -4 -4 -4
5.00000000 5 5 5           -4.00000000 -4 -4 -4
```